# Is any version of a Gaussian Process a Gaussian Process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am a bit confusing with the meaning of version of a Gaussian process, and of a stochastic process in general.

In https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02582 I find the following definition (Def 4.8).

*If $f$ is a Gaussian Process on $X$, a stochastic process $\tilde f$ on $X$ is called a version of $f$ if $f(x) = \tilde f(x)$ with probability $1$, for all $x\in X$.*

My question is: assuming that $\tilde f$ is a version of $f$, can we claim that it is a Gaussian Process?

I would say yes, since for all $x\in X$, $f(x)$ and $\tilde f(x)$ are equal almost surely, and so have the same distribution. Then any finite linear combinations $\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_if(x_i)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\tilde f(x_i)$ will have the same distribution as well. And hence the fact that $f$ is a Gaussian Process implies that $\tilde f$ is a Gaussian Process.

Am I right? So can I claim that all versions of a Gaussian Process with mean function $m$ ad covariance function $\Sigma$ are Gaussian Processes with the same mean function and covariance function?

Comment: Yes, all versions of a stochastic process have the same finite dimensional laws, essentially for the reason you said, and confirmed by Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process#Modification

Comment: Thank you @MikeEarnest